# Storing new objects of various datatypes in an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, objective-c-literals

The Realm migration example on the [Realm documentation site](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.89.1/#migrations) shows an example with a new `NSString` object. The example is simple and well explained.

```
if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
    newObject[@"email"] = @"";  // creates an NSString object...
}
```

But what about objects other than `NSString`? How does the code snippet need to be adapted in order to create objects of these other data types?

- `NSDate`
- `NSData`
- `RLMArray`
- `NSInteger`, `int`
- `double`, `float`, `CGFloat`
- `long`
- `bool`, `BOOL`

Answer (score 3):

Only certain types of object in ObjC/Cocoa have a literal shortcut like this. (Historically, `NSString` was in fact the *sole* class with such syntax, but several were [added recently-ish by the Clang compiler](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).)

There is no literal syntax for `NSDate`, `NSData`, or `RLMArray`; these need to be created with an appropriate construction method.

Primitive types like `double`, `long`, and `BOOL` cannot be stored directly in an `NSDictionary`, but they can be wrapped up using the "sugar" `@()`, i.e.:

```
newObject[@"numFrobs"] = @(anInteger);
```

This puts the value into an `NSNumber` instance, which then needs to be unwrapped to retrieve the primitive value:

```
NSInteger numFrobs = [newObject[@"numFrobs"] integerValue];
```

Comment: One more question: As I understood, realm-migration does an object-enumeration ([migration enumerateObjects:Person.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {...}) - but how would you create the "appropriate construction method" you mentioned for the more complicated NSData, NSDate, RLMArray ?? Do you have an example, maybe ? Thanks for any help on this !

Comment: I just mean the normal creation methods: `[NSDate date]`, `[NSData dataWithBytes:]`, e.g.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to think of it is just as if you were to create an Object in memory in your code. @"" is short form for NSString but you could use [NSString stringWithFormat:@""] as well

Comment: No, don't use `stringWithFormat:` unless you actually have a format string.